# ffmpeg high packet loss with UDP output

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, streaming, udp

I'm trying to transcode our hls streams into UDP multicast stream using ffmpeg, and I'm getting too many lost packets.

I'm using following command to transcode

```
ffmpeg \
-loglevel warning \
-nostats \
-re \
-max_reload 2 \
-i "http://hls-server/stream/playlist.m3u8" \
-c:v copy \
-c:a copy \
-f mpegts \
-flush_packets 0 \
"udp://remote-ip:40001?pkt_size=1316&buffer_size=8388608"
```

on the remote host I'm running client that checks mpegts headers continuity counter, and I'm getting an errors few times a minute.

I've tested the link between servers using iperf - 100 mb/s for half a hour without single packet lost.

I had this test running in parallel with ffmpeg and there was aforementioned packet loss for ffmpeg stream, but no packet loss for iperf.

I've already tried tweaking net.core.rmem_max and net.core.wmem_max with no success. I've tried increasing nic buffers using `ethtool -G tx xxx` also with no success. And I've already tried multiple versions of ffmpeg 3.3.9, 3.4.5, 4.0.3, and 4.1.

Do anyone have idea what could case this issue and how to fix it?